# Neo4j How to write Dot in Properties or Relations

Tags: neo4j

I have a problem that is specific. After I load the triples from RDF file thanks to plugin, some properties or relations are look like:

Relation Example ===> [:Country.city]
Property Example ==> city.name

there is a dot in property name and relation name. They can be created thanks to plugin There is no problem. But when i write query from this 127.0.0.1:7474 interface, i cant write dot '.' in property name or relation name. But the property name is contain dot. I need to write it .

Result : Syntax error invalid input '.'

How can I write correctly this property or relation name?

Comment: Query Example   MATCH (x)-[:Country.city]->(y) RETURN x,y

Comment: Query Example2 MATCH (x)-[:Contain]->(y) WHERE x.city.name="London" RETURN x,y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the entire relationship type or property name with backticks.

```
MATCH (x)-[:`Country.city`]->(y) RETURN x,y
...
MATCH (x)-[:Contain]->(y) WHERE x.`city.name`="London" RETURN x,y
```